# Multiple FMP sessions on a filemaker server

Tags: filemaker

I am a FMP server novice but I have a solution that I'm interested in hosting it online via instant web publishing. It's dependent on a user_id being held in a global variable through the life of the session (e.g. log in, cache user_id, use user_id through the session).

This is obviously fine in a single instance, but I'm wondering how the server will handle it if another session starts  ... is it able to run multiple session instances? (e.g. I have 2 users logged into two parallel running sessions, with 2 instances of user_id, both holding unique values)

I'd appreciate your thoughts.
with thanks
Giles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global variables (and global fields) are global only for a login. They are not pushed to the server and will not affect other sessions. So your user_id example should work fine.

FileMaker's help probably puts it best:

> Global field values are global to the user, not to the database. Each guest maintains values in their global fields separate from other guests.
>
> When a guest opens a file, the global field values are copied from the values for the host into the guest. If the guest's global field values are then changed, such as by running a script, they are changed just for that guest. They are not changed for the host or any other guests.

source: http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3604/kw/3604

Comment: Worth noting, the initial value for globals is the value they were set to in single-user mode.